# Azure Resource Group Organization

Tags: azure, azure-resource-group

I realize there probably isn't a single answer to this but I'm curious if there's any accepted best-practices or consensus on how resource groups and subscriptions should be organized.

Let's say you have a bunch of environments like dev, test, staging, and production. And your product is composed of N number of services, databases, and so on. Two thoughts come to mind:

1. Subscription per environment: use a different subscription for every environment and create resource groups for different subsystems within the environment. The challenge I have with this is it's not always obvious how to organize things. Say you have two subsystems that communicate through a service bus. Which resource group does the service bus itself belong to? The increased granularity is a nice option but in practice for me rarely used.
2. Resource group per environment: share the same subscription across all environments and use resource groups to group everything together. So you have a dev resource group, test resource group, and so on. This wouldn't give a ton of granularity but as I said that added granularity presents its own problems in my view.

Anyway, I'm just curious if there's any consensus or just thoughts on this. Cheers!

Comment: I think there should be more information as it will depend on a couple of scenarios.  How are you looking a deploying (Powershell, ARM, portal)? How will security be handled (Subscription, resource group, both?) What type of resources are you looking to deploy (Network, VMs, Apps, Databases, blobs, etc...)

Answer (score 2):

There's no right or wrong for this. I personally organize using Resource Groups / Application Level

rg-dev-app-a
rg-dev-app-b

rg-qa-app-a
rg-qa-app-b

and so on. You can also work with tags, which helps when dealing with shared resources between environments (dev / qa) or apps.

You can also find useful information in here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-adoption-framework/ready/azure-best-practices/naming-and-tagging

PS: I don't work with different subscriptions because there's no easy way (without powershell) to move resources between subscriptions (if needed).